# Get hexadecimal encrypted string in AES 256 Crypto++

Tags: c++, encryption, crypto++

I am trying to implement the AES 256 algorithm using Crypto++ in MS visual studio. Operating system is Windows 7 (64 bit).

I need to provide the key as a hexadecimal string, password as string and finally i want the encrypted string to also be hexadecimal string.

Here is what I am trying to do:

My encrypt method:

```
std::string encrypt(const std::string &password)
{
    std::string plain = password;
    std::string ciphertext;
    char * decodedKey= "729308A8E815F6A46EB3A8AE6D5463CA7B64A0E2E11BC26A68106FC7697E727E37011";

    byte key[ CryptoPP::AES::MAX_KEYLENGTH ], iv[ CryptoPP::AES::BLOCKSIZE ];
    CryptoPP::StringSource( reinterpret_cast<const char *>(decodedKey), true,
              new  CryptoPP::HashFilter(*(new  CryptoPP::SHA256), new CryptoPP::ArraySink(key, CryptoPP::AES::MAX_KEYLENGTH)) );
    memset( iv, 0x00,  CryptoPP::AES::BLOCKSIZE );

    CryptoPP::CBC_Mode<CryptoPP::AES>::Encryption Encryptor( key, sizeof(key), iv );
    CryptoPP::StringSource( plain, true, new CryptoPP::StreamTransformationFilter( Encryptor,
              new CryptoPP::HexEncoder(new CryptoPP::StringSink( ciphertext ) ) ) );

    std::cout<<"Ciphertext:" << ciphertext;
    return ciphertext;
}
```

From main method

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    encrypt("test");
    return 0;
}
```

At present I am hardcoding the key just for debugging purposes. My key is hexadecimal string as seen below. I need to get the output encrypted string as hex string.

Comment: All of this crypto++ aside -- what is your ultimate question?  Is it how to translate from an alpha string to two-digit per character hex string?

Comment: Try doing something with the return value of your function besides letting it fall into the ether?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I need to provide the key as a hexadecimal string, password as string and finally i want the encrypted string to also be hexadecimal string.

This is covered in the Crypto++ wiki (there's lots of examples in there ready for copy/paste). From [HexDecoder's Scripting and Strings](http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/HexDecoder#Scripting_and_Strings):

> On occasion, the mailing list will receive questions on
>   cross-validation. For example, see AES CTR Chiper. Different output
>   between PHP-mcrypt and Crypto++. In the question, PHP-mcrypt strings
>   are used as follows:
>
> ```
> $key = "1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234";
> $key = pack("H".strlen($key), $key);
> $iv = "1111111111222222222233333333334444444444555555555566666666667777";
> $iv = pack("H".strlen($iv), $iv);
> ```
>
> One of the easiest ways to avoid typos is via Copy/Paste and a
>   HexDecoder:
>
> ```
> string encodedKey = "1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234";
> string encodedIv = "1111111111222222222233333333334444444444555555555566666666667777";
> string key, iv;
>
> StringSource ssk(encodedKey, true /*pumpAll*/,
>     new HexDecoder(
>         new StringSink(key)
>     ) // HexDecoder
> ); // StringSource
>
> StringSource ssv(encodedIv, true /*pumpAll*/,
>     new HexDecoder(
>         new StringSink(iv)
>     ) // HexDecoder
> ); // StringSource
> ```

After running the above code, `key` and `iv` are hexadecimal (i.e., binary) strings rather than printable (i.e., ASCII) strings.

Comment: Please can u check this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21965102/aes-256-encryption-qt-equivalent-for-java  ..it states the actual problem

Comment: Parth - I'm not a Java guy and I rarely work with it. The Java folks would be in a better position to answer your questions.

Comment: yes the HexDecoder worked fine and the problem is resolved. Advise to all..please refer Crypto++ docs